# How to understand "return" as parameter direction?

Tags: parameters, uml, return, direction, out

In UML2.3 superstructure document, section 7.3.42 ParameterDirectionKind, there is a Description for the enumeration of the literal values:

in/inout/out/return

It is easy to understand "in" and "inout" from implementation perspective.

In C++ for example, "in" can be implemented in two ways:

```
foo( CString strParam )
bar( const CString& strParam )
```

"inout" can be also implemented in two ways: (reference & pointer)

```
foo( CString* pParam )
bar( CString& strParam)
```

**Now comes to my question:**

1. What does "return" mean? (I'm talking about "return" direction for a parameter, not return type for an operation/method)

   Are there any language support this direction of parameter? What is the code looks like.

   If no language support it, how to use it conventionally?
2. What is the difference between "return" and "out"?
3. Any implementation code for "out" direction of a parameter?

**In my opinion,** whenever we are talking about a parameter, there must be a caller call this function with an argument assigned to the parameter. Is this statement correct?

Then based on the parameter's direction, it could be in/inout/out/return. My question is: what does "return" direction mean? There must be a reason for the OMG to put this type in the document that I did not figure out.

**From UML2.3 Superstructure 7.3.42**

return:Indicates that parameter values are passed as return values from a behavioral element back to the caller.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in UML, the "return parameter" is what is returned and can have only one.  Think of it from the perspective of being inside the method (not from the perspective of real life language design as you know it).  The return parameter is what the entity passes to what invoked it.

Comment: This is what UML superstructure stated: return: Indicates that parameter values are passed as return values from a behavioral element back to the caller.

Comment: Exactly what I said.  If you are confused by them being called "parameters", don't.  UML was not designed to be language-centric.  Just because you're accustomed to languages "returning" values to be assigned to things on the left side of an equal sign, don't skew your perception of what that thing being passed actually is.  It is a parameter (for the assignment operation that follows, if you will).

Comment: Thank you Marty. In my opinion, whenever we are talking about a parameter, there must be a caller call this function with an argument assigned to the parameter. Is this statement correct? If yes, then what is the argument like to bind to a "return" direction parameter? Or am I talking about the language again :)  . From your saying, I ask in a different way. Why people use "return" direction parameter instead of "return" value? Are there any concrete examples?  Cheers

Comment: "binding" is just the action of storing something.  In common dialog we do say "return value" a lot, but you do not always return values :) sometimes you are returning a reference to a value, for example.  Return direction parameter was invented by UML to disconnect it from the real world of how languages are implemented.  There could be a language in fantasy land that always requires you to pass a variable parameter to a function in order to get the result.

Comment: or to be extreme, we could have a language implemented like this (made this up off the top of my head)    declare funtion1(param) { dowork and then goto function2(resultoffunction1)}  declare function2(param) { }    resultoffunction1 is a "return parameter from function1 which is passed to function2 which is just continuing with the rest of the program"

Comment: Anyway, my point is that UML is a generic language to describe system which is programming language independent.

Comment: In C/C++ (and their family) return parameters are different from the other types of parameters in that they do not have to come from the caller (although you could pass one of the callers parameters back to it)

Comment: Hmmm~~, I agree with you on the point that UML is programming language independent. But may I say some disagreement about your example :), "resultoffunction1" is an argument to function2, it is a variable of function1, I cannot see any "return" direction meaning from it.

Comment: Maybe there is a fantasy language with following conversions: 1. when you specify "in" parameter, the function can not change the value of the parameter; 2. when you specify "out" parameter, the function can not use the value of the parameter (bind to the argument); 3. when you specify a "return" parameter, ha I've thought a great idea to explain it..

Comment: I know, I made up a crazy example.  My point is still the same.  the return direction implies generically in the structure that it is the end result of some encapsulated operation which is returned (passed) to some other encapsulated entity for further use.  In the case of return it is passed to that which invoked the operation.  The invoker is self contained and received the passed result.  Returning ans passing all depend on your perspective.  The perspective is from within the scope returning it.  Imagine yourself INSIDE the function, not looking at it from the outside.

Comment: The fantasy language does not support "return" type of a function. The author of this fantasy language has this reason: In C++, a return type is not part of a function's signature, this sometimes caused a bug. For example: int foo(int a); void foo(int b); In C++, they can not be distinguished just by return type. This fantasy language works in this way: foo(int a, return int val); foo(int a, return void); Then the caller specify the argument in this way: int iReturnVal; foo(10, iReturnVal);  foo(10, null);

Comment: I think I just realized the semantics that are confusing you.  It is a return parameter, not a return ARGUMENT.  Parameter is just a package of something that flows through some channel as defined by the arguments of the function (for example).  Arguments are the declaration of WHAT is coming in.  Parameters are the actual things that flow through those channels.

Comment: Hmm~~, I think I know the difference between argument and parameter. for example: void foo(int a){}; here "a" is a parameter of foo. the caller called it with: int val = 10; foo(val); here "val" is the argument that passed into foo.

Comment: What really confused me is I've never seen a "return" parameter in an operation in any programming language as far as I know. So I'm curious about why UML support it and the relationship between a function's return type. Now I know that they can be exclusive, just let give placeholder for some fantasy language's implementation.